# What is the meaning of this Eclipse Java icon?

Tags: eclipse, icons

Most of my file icons in the editor tabs have a J-in-sheet-of-paper icon.  These are .java sources.  One icon looks different.

It is also a .java file, not essentially different from the rest as far as I can tell.  The icon has the J outside of a rectangle. The rectangle has a blue menu bar, so really it is a window-with-J-outside icon.

What does it mean?

I could not find this icon in the reference material at this link.

[Link to Eclipse icons](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Comment: unable to visualize, can u upload this icon somewhere and provide the link?

Answer (score 1):

I think you opened the .java file with "WindowBuilder Editor" or opened it once that way. (right click "open with")
If you double click the file now, eclipse seems to remember the last editor used for this.

Answer (score 0):

That icon is somewhat correlated with Swing-related .java files.  The correlation might be +1.0 but I haven't proven it.